# Beats Music API returns m3u8 for audio playback?

Tags: beatsmusic

I want to be able to stream music on a mobile device. Does the Beats Music API allow a m3u8 file asset to be returned?

Right now, only a RTMP stream is returned for audio playback.

Comment: As I know, m3u8 is only a playlist format (i.e. the utf-8 variant of m3u), you still need a link to the actual media to stream itself. What is your use case/scenario?

Comment: I would like to stream the mp3 on iOS and Android in native app. both do not have native support for RTMP media playback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, playback is authorized on the web player only. We are working on improving the use of playback, which will be easier to use.